# How to start a script when there is incoming traffic on a specified port?

Tags: networking, router, port, minecraft, traffic

I'd like to automate the start of my mc-server when I am logged onto my computer.
I have registered a public DNS, which is available 24/7. There is nothing running on that domain though, as it is just used for a clearer IP for my mc-server.

The port my server can run on is forwarded by my router. My router sends a magic packet to WOL my computer, when there is incoming traffic (actually it can be anything, but that does not bother me as it's a random port which is used for nothing, as far as I know) on the port I have setup for Minecraft and on bootup my mc-server starts.

I'd like to use that same mechanism on my computer to start my server **when there is incoming traffic on that port while my computer is already awake**. But I do not know how that works or what software/setup to use.

I suppose that I need to watch the traffic on my specified port, but I don't know how to automate all of that and run a script once someone tries to connect. I have read a lot of vague things online, which included some *docker daemon magic or even portqry or netstat usage*, however I could not make a lot of sense of those. If there is more to that, let me know please.

Another possibility I have come across is that I run a webserver on my Minecraft port once the server is down and then start my server via Javascript or something alike?

Please keep in mind that I don't want this to conflict the WOL setup of my router and computer.

**TL;DR: How to start a script when there is incoming traffic on a specified port?**

*For context: I already asked this question on the arqade forum, however someone in the comments pointed out, that it would be more appropriate here. I suppose that's true, because the context of the game server does not really matter.*

Comment: well, a port can only be opened by a process, so you need a program of some type to establish the port in the first place and put it in a listening state. no traffic can be received without a program. That very program (whatever it is) could start your script whenever you deem it appropriate.  or perhaps you need your script to open the port and then just sit idle until traffic is received. that is probably your best bet

Comment: @FrankThomas Okay, i'm not certain what you are getting at. The "program" you are referring to is exactly what I'm asking about, hence "how to start a script...".

Comment: well, you'd have to write one yourself. what I was trying to highlight, is that a port doesn't exist until a program of some kind establishes one, and that program is the only thing that can send/receive data to/from that port. many people think that all ports exist all the time and they are either opened or closed, which implies the OS is managing all of them, but that is incorrect. if you don't have a webserver listing on port 80, its not that port 80 is "closed", it means that it doesn't exist at all. so I encourage you to make your script network aware, so it can be the program you need.

Comment: @FrankThomas okay, thanks. I think harrymc's answer already guided me into the right direction. I'll just write a simple windows service with the tcp/udp-listener. That would be sufficient, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not available in Windows, so you will need to
create yourself a listener program on this port that will do some
action upon receiving some specific input text.

To get you started, here are two possibilities :

- [Blogpost - Create a TCP/UDP listener](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/blogpost-create-a-tcp-udp-listener/m-p/3596961)
  contains the source-code for a PowerShell script that listens on a port
  and outputs to the console the text messages that it receives.
  You may easily adapt it to your need.
- [Port Listener](https://github.com/AndrewSav/PortListener)
  is an open-source project for Visual Studio.

Comment: I'll look into this. Seems promising, I'll mark your answer as correct, once the setup (hopefully) works!